# DirectX11, HLSL - Texture2DArray Example?

Tags: shader, directx-11, hlsl

I know that Texture2DArray is available in HLSL, which can allocate an array of multiple textures initialized in C++ code as a shader resource. However, we do not find an example of exactly how to assign multiple ID3D11SHaderReosurceView*s to shaders by making them into one array.
If anyone knows about the process, could you give me an example?

- how to creare 1 shader reosurce view to set Texture2DArray with several ID3D11Resource or ID3D11ShaderResourceView that created by WICCreateTexture().

```cpp
Texture2DArray diffuses  : register(t0);
Texture2DArray normalmap : register(t1);
Texture2DArray metalics  : register(t2);
Texture2DArray opacities : register(t3);
```

*edit

```cpp
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA subresource;
    ZeroMemory(&subresource, sizeof(subresource));
    subresource.pSysMem = ???;

    ID3D11Texture2D* texture = nullptr;
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texture_desc;
    ZeroMemory(&texture_desc, sizeof(texture_desc));
    texture_desc.ArraySize = 10;

    DX11APP->GetDevice()->CreateTexture2D(&texture_desc, &subresource, &texture);

    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* res_view = nullptr;
    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC res_desc;
    ZeroMemory(&res_view, sizeof(res_view));

    res_desc.Texture2DArray.ArraySize = 10; // just example, array size can be changed at runtime.
    res_desc.Texture2DArray.FirstArraySlice = 0;
    res_desc.Texture2DArray.MipLevels = 0;
    res_desc.Texture2DArray.MostDetailedMip = 0;

    DX11APP->GetDevice()->CreateShaderResourceView(texture, &res_desc, &res_view);
```

is this right? So exactly what kind of value should be assigned to subresource.pSysMem?
start memory ptr of vector<ID3D11Resource*> or vector<ID3D11ShaderResourceView*>?

Answer (score 0):

**Texture2DArray** objects must be allocated as a unit. You cannot 'assemble' existing Texture2D resources into an array at runtime.

You have two approaches here:

## Runtime

1. Load each individual image as a Texture2D resource at runtime.
2. Create a Texture2DArray resource with `D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC.ArraySize` set to the number of images.
3. Copy each subresource of the individual textures into the texture 2D array.

## Offline

1. Create a Texture2DArray DDS file offline using a tool like [texassemble](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/Texassemble).
2. Load the DDS file at runtime using **DDSTextureLoader** which can create a Texture2DArray directly.

Comment: So how to store the ID3D11Resource of each texture in the pSysMem of D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA and hand over the multiple ID3D11Texture2Ds made in that way to Shader?